# How do I display my user's errors?

Tags: python, validation

My user wants to make a password and I'm supposed to be checking if it's valid or not. So far, I have down the code to check if it is valid/not valid. Now, the next step (after determining it is not valid) is to tell the user it is not valid AND why their password is not a valid option.

```
while True:
   pw = input('Enter password to be tested if valid or not: ')
   correct_length = False
   uc_letter = False
   lc_letter = False
   no_blanks = True
   first_letter = False

   if len(pw) >= 8:
   correct_length = True

   for ch in pw:
      if ch.isupper():
         uc_letter = True

      if ch.islower():
         lc_letter = True

   if pw.isalnum():
      digit = True

   if pw[:1].isalpha():
      first_letter = True

   if not pw.find(' '):
      no_blanks = True

   if correct_length and uc_letter and lc_letter and digit and first_letter and no_blanks:
      valid_pw = True
      print('Your password to be tested is valid.')
   else:
      valid_pw = False
      print('Your password to be tested is not valid because:')
      print(----------)
      #This is the part where I'm suppose to display the errors if the user gets it wrong.
      #Initially, in the test for ch. above, I put in an else: with a print statement but because of the for- statement, it prints it out for every single character.

   answer = input('Try another password input? y/n ')
   if answer == 'y':
      answer = True
   else:
      break
```

Comment: just check which one of your tests parameter are false. Better approach is to put the parameters in a dictionary as key and true/false as value; then it's dead simple to extract the false ones.

Comment: If it's a web application, you should consider doing client-side validation and server-side validation.  The client side validation would be written in JavaScript, and the server side validation could be in Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You check for all valid conditions. The correct approach is, instead of checking for the condition to be true like this,

```
if len(pw) >= 8:
   correct_length = True
```

check for

```
if len(pw) < 8:
   correct_length = False
   print "Password not lengthy"
```

This will help identify the error. basically, find what all evaluate to false, so that the user could be pointed out those errors.

Comment: Thank you! Your suggestion jogged my brain and I was able to take your idea and find a way to display them! I used an additional 'else:' and some extra 'if' statements; it was tedious and took up more lines but it works regardless! Thank you again, you gave me the nudge I needed to finish :D

Answer (score 1):

Hm.. I think you can simply put the extra `else` statement, then raise an error:

```
   if not pw.find(' '):
      no_blanks = True
   else:
      raise ValueError('Invalid input!')
```

And similarly with your other conditionals.

If you want your loop to keep going, you can just print the message, and then continue:

```
else:
    print("Invalid input! Please re enter it:")
    continue
```

Hope this helps!